# Two combobox with same DataSet but with different query's

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, combobox, vb.net-2010

I tried searching for an answer to this question the whole day but have been unable to find one.

I want to have two comboboxes on the same form but have them display different data by query. One combobox is to Assign the Room Selected and the other one would be to Unassign the room selected on the second combobox. I have an Access DataBase and one of the tables have 4 fields (ID, Room Name, Active(checkbox = yes/no), Room Lended(checkbox = yes/no). Basically I want the first combobox to only display the Rooms name that are not lended so I can assign them and the other combobox to display only the rooms that are lended so I can unassign them once they become free.

I have tested the query's that I made and work fine when I preview the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a minute to grasp what you're going for as it's very different than how I would have constructed it.  Essentially you have a very basic table and the right idea, but your approach is complicating the task. 
Simplest solution I can think of is to start a new form based on the table (I know, I know; but I said simplest) and drag all your fields onto the form (or get them there in your preferred manner)  If the ID is for linking only, hide it if you like. If you want to see a bunch of rooms at once, make it a continuous rows form.  Me, I'd want a note area for each room linked in a sub form below the main data, but that's me.  Anyway.  On your two Boolean (Yes/No) fields, put a simple expression in the after update event: IIf(Active, Lended = -1, Lended = 0) in the Room Active field and reverse it for the Lended.  (Access assumes a 'True' so you don't have to specify '=True' or = '-1' in your expression unless it helps you see the logic better.  Obviously my names are not yours, adjust accordingly.

Then you can use your two queries for quick view reports or forms to see all Available or all Reserved rooms.

Craig

Comment: Thanks for you're response Craig!

I'm still kind of in the blue tho. I tried adding a image to better illustrate what I'm trying to do but I still cant >.<

This is how I have it in mind. User just selects a Room to Assign by its name and clicks Assign button and that would lead him to another form where he enters all the data necessary. On the other combobox the user can only select the Rooms that are already Assigned and can only Unassigned them which means they become free or renew the time for an extra hour.

Comment: I was thinking there could be a way to assign the same data table but make a copy of it or something and assign different queries to both of them and just have them reference each combo box by its own. I want to try and have them both in the same form so that way I don't clog up the application with many forms and to not have the user going to different forms for things that he could have done all in just one.

Comment: Thought it was too simple to be true.  :-)  When you start adding other elements (such as time) your available options increase exponentially. So based on your clarification, what you may just want is an unbound form with your two combo boxes- one based on your available rooms query, the other on the unavailable rooms query. Selecting either will get you the room ID (Provided it's in the query) and you can open the form from there.  You can do it under the hood using the after update event or simply add a button under each combo box and use the associated combobox for the ID field.